# Why Python.h of python 3.2 must be included as first together with Qt4

Tags: c++, python, qt

I have a qt application and I want to implement python interpreter into it so that I can extend it with python scripts. While this works fine for regular C++ application, including Python.h even for most simple, empty Qt4 project always result in:

```
g++ -c -m64 -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -DQT_WEBKIT -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -I. -I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore -I/usr/include/qt4 -I/usr/include/python3.2mu -I. -o main.o main.cpp
In file included from /usr/include/python3.2mu/Python.h:8:0,
                 from main.cpp:16:
/usr/include/python3.2mu/pyconfig.h:1182:0: warning: "_POSIX_C_SOURCE" redefined [enabled by default]
/usr/include/features.h:164:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
/usr/include/python3.2mu/pyconfig.h:1204:0: warning: "_XOPEN_SOURCE" redefined [enabled by default]
/usr/include/features.h:166:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
In file included from /usr/include/python3.2mu/Python.h:67:0,
                 from main.cpp:16:
/usr/include/python3.2mu/object.h:402:23: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘;’ token
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
```

I only implemented this in my .pro file:

INCLUDEPATH += "/usr/include/python3.2"

now anytime when I do

```
#include <Python.h>
```

in any .h file it makes it unbuildable. Why is that?

**Note: This all works perfectly with python 2.7, just python 3x doesn't work**

EDIT: I figured out, that when I include Python.h as first file, before Qt includes, it works, is this a bug in python? Are they missing some safe guards?

Answer (score 3):

The [documentation](http://docs.python.org/3.2/c-api/intro.html#include-files) of the Python C-API states:

> **Note** Since Python may define some pre-processor definitions which affect the standard headers on some systems, you must include Python.h before any standard headers are included.

It is very likely that some of the Qt headers include standard headers (as evident from the error you get, it does include `/usr/include/features.h`, or example), therefore `#include <Python.h>` should be placed before the Qt headers. In fact, it should generally be placed before any other include-statement.

Note that this is the case with Python 2.7, too. If a different include order works for you with Python 2.7, then you are simply lucky.

Comment: This sounds incredibly selfish, if every developer were thinking like this, we couldn't use more than 1 foreign library, because they would all need to be included first. Why aren't they safeguarding this?

Comment: @Petr I ultimately don't know the answer to that, and I am not saying this optimal. But one thing to keep in mind is that they do not simply create name clashes deliberatly. What the text above means, I believe, is that they purposefully affect certain standard headers.

Comment: Which is broken. They should instead require that users define the relevant `_XOPEN_SOURCE` and `_POSIX_SOURCE` macros to sufficient values before including Python.h, instead of redefining them.